# How to makes divs responsive and stack them vertically?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make 2 `div`s responsive, so when a mobile device is used, the 2 internal `div`s will be stacked vertically, one on top of the other.

I have the HTML for the `div`s (unresponsive), but I don't know what I need to do with the CSS to make them responsive:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 50%; float: left;"> Left </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 50%;"> Right </div>
</div>
```

I have a JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3ktku6ss/1/).

Comment: you can try using bootstrap css for responsive thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set both inner divs float to the left and use media queries to specify different width depending on the screen:

```
div.inner{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width:768px){
    div.inner{
        width: 50%;
}
```

Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qs3frhb5/).

Actually, this is the same what bootstrap grid system do - so you should try it.

Comment: Thanks @chem1st. What you describe is exactly how I want it. However, when I apply the code to my site, it doesn't function like your code. Nothing happens. I tried using Bootstrap code too and same thing nothing happens. Why isn't it being applied?

Comment: Have you tried to inspect your code in browser? Is the css file loaded correctly?

Comment: Got it, one of the divs wasn't wrappered in a .container-fluid div. Works now. Thanks for the tip, Bootstrap is very useful.

Comment: Glad to help, will be appreciate for an upwote from you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use flexbox:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;    /* Magic begins */
  flex-wrap: wrap;  /* Allow multiple lines */
}
#wrapper > div {
  flex: 1;          /* Distribute space equally among the flex items */
  min-width: 300px; /* But force them to be at least300px wide */
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet for the responsiveness. You need to use media queries to apply different css for different width devices. So, i apply different CSS for the child 2 divs for less then 768px width device. If you resize your browser or check the page on mobile, you'll see those 2 divs are stacked vertically.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
    position:relative;
}

.container:after{
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display:block;
}

.col-half{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}

@media only screen  and (max-width: 767px){
    .col-half{
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-half"> Left </div>
    <div class="col-half"> Right </div>
</div>
```